# R Shiny selectizeInput to matrix for stars plot

Tags: r, shiny, selectize.js

In my application the user can upload any .csv file  and plot it *(I have simplified example by using an online file, and I realise the example plot is pretty useless)*. I am currently having trouble with plotting the stars symbol from the user input.

I want to use a selectizeInput so they can select any number of the columns to plot as the length of the rays. The stars need to take a matrix of the columns but I think selectize returns as a list.

The method I used in the code below shows what I want but it only takes so many columns. I assume there is an easy way to do this but I am quite new to R and could not find anything that worked when I searched.

ui.R

```
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Scatterplot of star symbols"),
  sidebarPanel(
    selectizeInput("starSpokes", "Select colums for star spoke lengths", c("murder", "Forcible_rate", "Robbery", "aggravated_assult", "burglary"), multiple = TRUE)
  ),
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("graphPlot")
  )
))
```

server.R

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  crime = read.csv("http://datasets.flowingdata.com/crimeRatesByState2005.tsv", header = TRUE, sep ="\t") 

  output$graphPlot = renderPlot({
    starRays = cbind(crime[[input$starSpokes[1]]], crime[[input$starSpokes[2]]], crime[[input$starSpokes[3]]], crime[[input$starSpokes[4]]])
    symbols(x=crime$murder, y=crime$burglary, stars = starRays)
  })
})
```

I apologise if this has already been answered, I have searched but found nothing that works, possibly because I do not know the correct terms to search for or have implemented their methods wrong.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Values of the `selectizeInput` are simply a character vector so you can use it to select columns of the `crime` data frame. After that all you need is `as.matrix`.

```
output$graphPlot <- renderPlot({
    if(length(input$starSpokes) < 3) return()
    symbols(
        x=crime$murder, y=crime$burglary,
        stars=as.matrix(crime[, input$starSpokes])
    )
})
```

When you work with Shiny it is a good practice to check input and short-circuit if it doesn't meet criteria. Since `stars` require at least three columns there is no reason to evaluate the rest of the code if user didn't select required number of fields.

Comment: Thank you so much. Is there a way to find out the type of data returned from an input? I wasn't sure what was returned so was unsure of what exactly to search for, I don't believe there's anything about vectors on the shiny.rstudio page.

Comment: Straightforward by rather ugly way is to print `class` to the log or console.